# Is there a good way to use crossfilter to query multiple dimensions for unique values, not aggregates?

Tags: crossfilter

I've got a big set of data loaded into crossfilter for a dc.js project I'm working on.  Of course a number of my columns have repeated values in them and I'd like to be able to find the unique list of values in one column that correspond to the repeated values in another.  The sample data below probably illustrates the point more clearly.

```
var data = [
    { state: "WA", city: "Seattle",  data: "a" },
    { state: "WA", city: "Seattle",  data: "b" },
    { state: "WA", city: "Tacoma",   data: "c" },
    { state: "OR", city: "Portland", data: "d" },
    { state: "OR", city: "Bend",     data: "e" },
    { state: "OR", city: "Bend",     data: "f" }
];
```

I'd like to be able to filter on a particular state and then find the unique list of cities for that state.  So, if the input was "WA", I'd like get back a two element array containing "Seattle" and "Tacoma".  The code below actually does exactly that (and also provides the counts, though I really don't care about those) but having to create a second crossfilter object feels very clumsy to me.  I also don't know about the performance since I'll end up having to iterate through this several times, once for each state.

```
var Ndx = crossfilter(data);
var stateDim = Ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.state; });
var cityDim = Ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.city; });

var stateFilter = stateDim.filter("WA");
var stateRows = stateFilter.top(Infinity);

// It seems like there should be a better way than this.
var cityNdx = crossfilter(stateRows);
var cityDim2 = cityNdx.dimension(function (d) { return d.city; });
var cites = cityDim2.group().top(Infinity);

cites.forEach(function(d) {
    console.log("City: " + d.key + ", Count: " + d.value);
});

/* --------------------------- *\
Log output:

City: Seattle, Count: 2
City: Tacoma, Count: 1

\* --------------------------- */
```

It seems like the should be a way to get to this kind of result with some filtering, grouping, or reducing strategy, but after spending *way* too much time trying, I haven't been able to come up with one.  All the examples I've seen that use multiple dimensions produce aggregates, but that's not what I need.  I need values.  Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a custom reduce function to keep an array of all city values that have appeared for a given state. Something like the following (completely untested - sorry) should work:

```
var Ndx = crossfilter(data);
var stateDim = Ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.state; });
var stateGroup = stateDim.group().reduce(
  function(p, v) {
    p.count++;
    if(p.uniques.indexOf(v.city) === -1) p.uniques.push(v.city);
  },
  function(p, v) {
    p.count--;
    // Note: uniques are not filtered. You need to use a map and keep
    // count of uniques to have uniques that match your current filter
  },
  function() {
    return { count: 0, uniques: [] };
  }
);

stateGroup.top(Infinity).forEach( function(g) {
  console.log("State " + g.key + " has count " + g.value.count);
  console.log("Unique cities in " + g.key + ":");

  g.value.uniques.forEach(function (c) {
    console.log(c);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I found it necessary to make a few changes to adapt the basic concept to my scenario.  The most important thing was to apply a filter for the state values and then use Ndx.groupAll() so that the filter was observable in the .reduce() method.

Comment: I should also add that my actual data is about 9000 rows with about 11 states and 38 different cities in all.  My very crude performance measurements indicate that the two approaches were pretty comparable with creating a second crossfilter object being just a bit faster, which surprised me.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. I'd be interested to see your final code. If you post it as another answer or link a JSFiddle/JSBin from the original post, that would probably be easiest.

Comment: Because there was no clear gain in performance or simplicity I just ended up sticking with my original approach (i.e. using a second crossfilter).  The code in your answer provided the basic structure of my investigation into using reduce for this problem so I submitted edits to your answer to add the couple of pieces that got it to work for me.  I think you just need to approve the edits.

Comment: I can't see them. I think the edits were rejected by people with moderation karma because they changed the nature of my answer. The best way to provide your solution would probably be to edit your question and add a "found a solution" section.